# I'm trying to pass a question about how to create a button on a Udacity HTML course, but it keeps telling me to try again. Further explanation inside

Tags: html, button

**Here is the error message Udacity is giving me.**

Your code should:

Start with the opening HTML tag for a button element

Contain some text, but no HTML tags, in the middle

End with the closing tag for the button element.

**Here is my code.**

```
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<title>
<button type="button">
    I am a button
</button>
</title>`
```

I am using w3 validator and it is giving me no error or warning messages. I am stumped. What am I doing wrong?

I tried using w3 validator to correct my code, but it says I have no errors or warnings. I copied the code directly from MDN...

```
`<button class="favorite styled"
        type="button">
    Add to favorites
</button>`
```

...but that does not satisfy Udacity, either.

I coped the code from w3 schools dot com...

```
`<button type="button">Click Me!</button>`
```

...but that does not satisfy Udacity, either. I'm just at a loss as to how to get past this.

Comment: Instructions didn't say that you should include a type attribute, or that you should break this into multiple lines - so maybe that is what the check is picky about? Have you tried just `<button>Click Me!</button>`?

Comment: It's also says "*Start with the opening HTML tag for a button element*", but you are starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>`